# Contact form 7 WordPress plugin not showing sender email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I hope you'll take some mercy on me as I've been banging my head against the wall on this and the contact form 7 people want to charge me hundreds of dollars to troubleshoot something wrong with their plug-in that should be a simple fix.

I've triple and quadruple checked my settings and I know they are correct. For some reason I'm getting all the information when people send me emails through my contact form except for the sender's email address. all the mail tags between the form tab and mail tab match.

Please help! Thanks in advance.

MAIL TAB

From: [your-name] 
Subject: [your-subject]

Message Body:
[your-message]

--

### This e-mail was sent from a contact form on Naimah Jabali-Nash (http://www.naimahjnash.com)

Your Name (required)
    [text* your-name akismet:author]

Your Email (required)
    [email* your-email akismet:author_email]

Subject
    [text your-subject]

Your Message
    [textarea your-message]

[submit "Send"]

Comment: Don't know if this falls under programming -- i don't see any code. This may be a tech support question to the folks who made the plugin.

Comment: I don't see [your-email] field listed in MAIL TAB, if you want that field input sent to you, YOU SHOULD LIST THAT FIELD IN "MAIL TAB". You are welcome ;)